# How to add a row into the joinTable (cakephp)

Tags: cakephp

how can I add additionally a row into the joinTable users_books. I have created a BelongsToMany relation between users and books, which works very well. In the next step I want to add a record into my joinTable, but I haven't find a way how to do.

Comment: If you follow the CakePHP conventions, the users_books table will automatically populate when editing / adding books or users.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add just the two foreign keys  and others attributes if any in the table

```
insert into users_books(id_user,id_book) values (4,5);
```

Comment: thank you, but should it be possible to do it in a abstract way, such as by executing a cakephp method?